# Segmentation Fault. Unknown cause (Missing file?)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a lab assignment for class and writing an input function for a string header we are writing. The function basically just reads in strings from a FILE and stores them in the string object. It has features such as ignoring leading white space and being able to define a function to specify terminating characters that will stop the reading of the file.

The problem is that I'm receiving a segmentation fault, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I don't understand the error in GDB. My instructor seems to think it has something to do with 32-bit vs. 64-bit system architecture, but I'm not sure. Here is the error.

```
__strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcmp-ssse3.S:232
232     ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcmp-ssse3.S: No such file or directory.
```

Does anyone know specifically what this error means? A Google search turns up nothing.

Here's the function in question: http://pastebin.com/tNTEQKZX

I think the problem is that it continues to try to read new strings once it has reached the end of the file. It seems like it's not terminating on the EOF character.

Here is the program that is using the input function: http://pastebin.com/E3RinS24

Comment: This "missing file" is a source assembly file that gdb cannot find to show you source. Type the command "bt" to show the backtrace and move up to code you've written on that trace... the root cause of your error will likely be found there (but without posting your code here, nobody can give you a more direct answer).

Comment: The `No such file or directory` error shouldn't be related to your actual problem.  Everything GDB tries to tell you here is that it cannot show you the line of code where your segfault occurs (it's trying to open the _source_ file to show you, but doesn't find it).  You might show us some of your code and we might be able to help you investigate your real problem.

Comment: You get the "missing file" because it's part of the system library. You have to walk `up` the function call stack until you reach your own code. There you will probably find that you're passing a `NULL` pointer, or another equally illegal pointer (like an uninitialized local variable).

Comment: You have a bug in your loop discarding whitespace. You have to remember that the `scanf` family of function returns `EOF` only on error (or when reading beyond the end of the file of course). Otherwise it returns the number of successfully scanned entries, in your case it's normally `1`, which of course is "true", meaning you will always return from the function.

Comment: I've corrected that, instead now comparing eofCheck to EOF to determine whether or not to return an ERROR. Was that the only problem you found? I'm still getting a "memory corruption" error when running it that seems to indicate a problem with malloc'ing something.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the `mystring_push` function. And in the future, please *edit your question* to include your code. Don't add links to external sites.

Comment: Nevermind. The error was completely unrelated to the input function. The problem was in the push() function of my string library. It was realloc'ing memory in the wrong situations. Thanks for pointing out that EOF problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the `mystring_push` function. And in the future, please edit your question to include your code. Don't add links to external sites. –  Joachim Pileborg

Nevermind. The error was completely unrelated to the input function. The problem was in the push() function of my string library. It was realloc'ing memory in the wrong situations. Thanks for pointing out that EOF problem, though. –  Darin Beaudreau